# how to see form validation error in django view (not template)?

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I am using ajax and need to pull my errors from form validation via ajax.

I try the following, but it prints blank:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     print form.errors
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save() 
            except:
                 pass
```

What do I need to do to extract validation errors so that I can pass it to view via ajax, or even start with a print in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `form.errors` is printed inside `form.is_valid` condition, it will never show error.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the errors in the views.py file using something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
  response = form.save()
  return HttpResponse('ok inserted')
else:
  if form['fieldname'].errors:
    ... your code here ...
  return render(request, 'survey.html', context)
```